# Laravel multiple user id tables

Tags: database, laravel, foreign-keys, relationship

I'm pretty new to laravel and have a really basic question related to relationships.

Here is an example of my question:

I have a migration called `money_transfers`.
The migration contains the following things:

1. user_id (transfer sent by)
2. sentTo_id (transfer sent to)
3. amount
4. sent_at

BOTH `user_id` and `sentTo_id` refer to a User ID.

Now, what I want to do is the following:

Fetch the user the money was sent TO the same way as the user the money was sent BY. Just like in the example below:

```
$transfer->sentTo->name
```

or

```
$transfer->sentTo->id
```

You get what I mean. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: And what is the problem exactly? Just make multiple relations. Show code you have right now.

Comment: Did you add the relation to the model?

Comment: Yes, I added the relation to the model. What I mean is that both (user_id, sentTo_id) refer to a user. How can I make laravel know that sentTo_id is a user ID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you defined your *foreign keys* correctly in your migration table, Then it's just a matter of defining the right relationship:

```
class MoneyTransfer extends Model
{

   public function sentBy()
   {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');
   }



   public function sentTo()
   {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'sentTo_id');
   }
}
```

This way you can access the receiver attribute like this:

```
$transfer->sentTo->name;
```

And the sender attribute like this:

```
$transfer->sentBy->name;
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for. Thank you very much for helping.